# SQL Server (2012+) executed procedure stats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need executed stored procedure statistics: logical reads, physical reads, duration, writes, rowcount. Or, maybe we can simplify this. Its enough to have same session data. Something like SET STATISTICS IO ON/OFF, but, I need to save results to table. So, SET STATISTICS IO is not the option.
Any knowledge here?

I expect something like:

```
EXEC [my_proc];

INSERT INTO [sp_exec_stats]
([lreads], [preads], ..., [rcount])
VALUES(?, ?, ..., ?);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/tracking-stored-procedure-usage

Comment: Thanks for downvotes, but it is not duplicate. Please dive more in to the question.

Comment: Kindly provide some sample input, expected output and anything which you've tried. That's the reason I felt it was duplicate.

Comment: I provided code sample, what to be expected. Also my question exactly describes params to be tracked: logical reads, physical reads, duration, writes, rowcount.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found solution by myself.Please use this approach(whole test script, "select" part is the point):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [my_dummy_sp]
    @rowcount INT   OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [sys].[objects];
    SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    RETURN 0; 

END;    

GO


DECLARE @sp_exec_stats TABLE
(
     [rec_id]           BIGINT  IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[sp_name]          NVARCHAR(256)
    ,[db_name]          NVARCHAR(256)
    ,[sys_dt]           DATETIMEOFFSET(7)
    ,[logical_reads]    INT
    ,[physical_reads]   INT
    ,[duration]         INT
    ,[writes]           INT
    ,[rowcount]         INT
    ,[cpu_time]         INT
);

DECLARE @rowcount   INT;

EXECUTE [my_dummy_sp]
     @rowcount = @rowcount OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO @sp_exec_stats
(
     [sp_name]  
    ,[db_name]          
    ,[sys_dt]           
    ,[logical_reads]    
    ,[physical_reads]   
    ,[duration]         
    ,[writes]           
    ,[rowcount] 
    ,[cpu_time]     
)
SELECT TOP 1
     [sp_name]          = 'my_dummy_sp'
    ,[db_name]          = DB_NAME()     
    ,[sys_dt]           = [last_execution_time] 
    ,[logical_reads]    = [last_logical_reads]  
    ,[physical_reads]   = [last_physical_reads] 
    ,[duration]         = [last_elapsed_time]   
    ,[writes]           = [last_logical_writes] 
    ,[rowcount]         = @rowcount
    ,[cpu_time]         = [last_worker_time]    
FROM
    [sys].[dm_exec_procedure_stats]
WHERE
        [object_id]     =   OBJECT_ID('my_dummy_sp')    
ORDER BY 
     [last_execution_time] DESC;


DROP PROCEDURE [my_dummy_sp];
SELECT * FROM @sp_exec_stats;
```